# Can I generate a jar with maven without method bodies in Java?

Tags: java, maven

I would like to generate a jar using maven that does not contain any method bodies and only has declarations of public classes, methods and javadocs so other people can use as classpath(IDE linter reference). The actual jar with method bodies will be shipped separately. Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand your question but it sounds like you are searching for interfaces or abstract classes?

Comment: @PiRocks That does not help nor does it answer or tries to answer the question...

Comment: This is exactly how Android ships its library jar files: the actual implementations are not shipped and the jar file distributed this way are only useful for compiling code, but not for running it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer If I take that literally how should the implementation come onto the device? Or where should the code really run?

Comment: @khmarbaise: the implementations are part of the system image (i.e. they are shipped with the phone software). The jar files that are shipped with the SDK do not contain actual executable code, only classes that "look like" the real thing for the purpose of compiling against them.

Comment: So a usual API module...

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, something like that, is there a maven configuration to do that?

Comment: make simply two different modules one api which contains only interfaces and another which contains implementation...

Answer (score 2):

Extract Interfaces of all these classes. Then you assemble only these interfaces into your jar. The easiest way doing it with maven is to organize your project into two modules:

```
Interface
    src/main/....
Implementation
    src/main/....
```

each of them packaged as jar.

Comment: That could work, but is there anyway to do it automatically? like dropping all method bodies when compiling a jar or only returning placeholder values

Comment: Not that I know of. But IDE's like eclipse help you a lot for such refactoring tasks.